# mvc3 custom role provider error on Web.Config

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, roleprovider

I'm trying to figure this out for a few day now, i have custom membership and role providers for my project and it works perfectly on my dev machine, but on production it throws the following error for the web.config

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 24: <providers>
Line 25:         <clear />
Line 26:         <add name="FeelSafeRoleProvider" type="FeelSafe.Helpers.FeelSafeRoleProvider, FeelSafe" connectionStringName="FeelSafeEntities" />
Line 27:       </providers>
Line 28:     </roleManager>
```

> Source File: (...)\web.config    Line: 26

I've read about people having simmilar issues because they hadn't named their connectionstrings but my connectionstring is defined as follows

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="FeelSafeEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.FeelSafe.csdl|res://*/Models.FeelSafe.ssdl|res://*/Models.FeelSafe.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=PLESK-23\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FeelSafe;Persist Security Info=True;User ID={user};Password={password};MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

any toughts on what's going on here?
if you need any more info just ask and i'll provide.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found out that the problem wasn't directly with the role provider classes nor the connectionstring, the version of the MySQL connector was old, updating it solved this error.